# Detect if an object is on screen

Tags: android, image, api, view, detect

I'm writing an Android program I put a `ImageView` on screen and then remove it but another part of the code is still trying to detect the `ImageView` after it has been removed. How do I write an if statement that will allow me to detect if the `imageView` has been removed? I've tried a few things but get no result

```
    if (arrowObj000.get(6).findViewWithTag(arrowObj000.get(6))!=null) {

}
```

`arrowObj00` is a list object/array holding refrences to the `ImageView` this isn't the problem though

Problem is I need to write an if statement that detects if the `ImageView` is currently attached.

Comment: Did you try the method View.isShown()?

Answer (score 0):

Walk up the chain of parents, comparing each to the root view of the activity/fragment.  If you hit the root, you're attached.  If you find a null first, you aren't.

Although a better way to handle this would probably to store the state information somewhere and not use your view as state.

Answer (score 0):

After thoroughly looking through the code hints I found the answer

```
if (arrowObj000.get(6).isAttachedToWindow()) {

}
```